# Adding new SKSpriteNode to SKScene has large intermittent lag

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skview, skscene

I have a standard UIViewController (*TestViewController*), and in this controller's **viewWillLayoutSubviews** method I instantiate a new SKView subclass (*TestView*) and add it as a subview to the controller's view. In addition I add some buttons which are meant to let the user control actions in an SKScene subclass (*TestScene*). *TestScene* is instantiated in an **init** method on *TestView*. Immediately after *TestView* is added to *TestViewController's* view as a subview I also call **[testView presentScene]** which is a method on the *TestView* that simply calls **[self presentScene: testScene]**.

Pressing the mentioned buttons on *TestViewController* is meant to call a method on *TestScene* (via *TestView*) that will instantiate a new SKSpriteNode subclass (*TestSpriteNode*) and add it as a child to the scene. This does work, but my problem is that for the first *TestSpriteNode* to get added there is intermittently a long delay in the *TestScene* rendering the new sprite. From time to time it works perfectly but most of the time it will get stuck and after multiple touches of the button multiple sprites will appear all at once, after which everything functions perfectly. I should mention that this problem occurs on the simulator as well as on my device.

I have tried adding a new *TestSpriteNode* in the *TestScene's* -**(void)didMoveToView:(SKView*)view** resulting in the *TestSpriteNode* appearing immediately and then there being a delay when the button is pressed to add a new *TestSpriteNode*. By adding a break point to the method that the button press calls on *TestScene* I can see that it is called immediately but the added *TestSpriteNode* is not rendered immediately.

I apologise in advance if there is already an answer that addresses delays in rendering dynamically added SKSpriteNodes, I was not able to find it. Is there something that I have misunderstood about adding new SKSpriteNodes to an SKScene?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem here [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9203). Making new SKScenes for different screens rather than new UIViewControllers fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to say. But consider this: if the sprite uses a texture that hasn't been loaded into memory, creating the sprite will load the image file as a texture. The larger the image the longer it takes to load it. This will not happen for subsequent sprites using the same texture.

If you aren't already make sure all images are added to an SKTextureAtlas, and preload the texture atlas before or while creating the scene. The atlas will then allow you to get textures by image name and use them to create sprites without any texture-loading delays.

Comment: Thanks for tip @LearnCocos2D! This wasn't my issue but I will keep it in mind for the future.